# rotation problem in javascript animation using canvas

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to make a circle around another circle except that each turn the circles are not recreated in the same place so it doesn't work.

```
function init(){
  ctx.globaleCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);
  ctx.translate(800,400);
  [enter image description here][1]
 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.arc(0,0,110,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  ctx.rotate(0.1*Math.PI/180);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100,100,10,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  requestAnimationFrame(init);
}
init();
```

this is what it gives:
[image]

when i want that :
[image]

Comment: "[enter image description here][1] "   is not a part of the code

Comment: Are you trying to do an actual animation, that is have the little blue circle move around the larger one or do you just want a static picture as shown?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I do two things.

Mend the typo which has an extra e in globaleCompositeOperation

And I sort of guess at what you have set innerWidth and innerHeight to. Are these set somewhere?

If you could put up a snippet with everything in it to make it work that might help. I can’t make a snippet as I am on a touch only device I’m afraid.

Here’s my code

```
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
<script>
function init(){
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,1024,768);
  ctx.translate(0,0);
 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.arc(0,0,110,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  ctx.rotate(0.1*Math.PI/180);
​
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100,100,10,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
​
  requestAnimationFrame(init);
}
let c= document.getElementById('c');
let ctx = c.getContext('2d');
init();
</script>
```